# How to send integer array through SerialPort

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, integer, transmission

I have an integer array d:`int[] d = new int[]{1,2,3,4}`

I want to send this through serial port `(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`).
What I have written was

```
serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);//SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0].ToString(), 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
if(serialPort.IsOpen == false)
      serialPort.Open();
try
{
    //serialPort.Write(buffer_2_send, 0, buffer_2_send.Length);
    serialPort.Write(d, 0, d.Length);
    serialPort.WriteLine("43665");
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
}
```

And I am receiving this array `d` in another PC with Hercules RS232 software.
I am not seeing anything in Hercules screen for the line `serialPort.Write(d, 0, d.Length);`.
What would be the problem. The line  `serialPort.WriteLine("43665");` is writing the string "43665" to the Hercules screen.

Comment: Is Hercules listening?

Comment: I wonder how this can compile. AFAIK, there's no overload of serialPort.Write that works with an int[]. Are you, by chance, running and old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your integer array to byte array before you send(`serialPort.Write`) it to device

```
int[] d = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
byte[] buf = d.SelectMany(i => BitConverter.GetBytes(i)).ToArray();
```

But there are also other issues. What size does your device assume for int? 2,4,8 bytes? What is endianness, Little-endian or big endian etc. Maybe it is as simple as

```
byte[] buf = d.Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Vinod Not surprise. I mentioned the problems. Read your device manual to learn the format how it accepts integers.

Answer (score 0):

In Hercules context menu (right click on data window) you need to set special char treatment to hex (away from text mode).

I'd suppose Hercules is filtering non text characters like 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04. You could test that, if you put 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44 (which is ABCD) in your array and see what happens.